# What is the modulation used in a Honda Civic keyfob? And how can you find this out?

Tags: untagged

I'm using a Flipper Zero which and I want to decode my unlock signal which is rolling. The [FCC ID of the keyfob is N5F-A05TAA](https://fccid.io/N5F-A05TAA). I had calculated independently and later confirmed that the keyfob transmits on 313.85 mhz. How do I demodulate that signal? How do I find the modulation used? Many people seem to claim it's in the database at fccid.io, but as linked above I don't see it.

I've brute forced all the modulations available on the Flipper Zero, and I don't see a successful demodulation of a single signal under "Read". I'm using the Flipper Unleashed firmware.

According to [one datasheet](https://fccid.io/N5F-A05TAA/Test-Report/Test-Report-1321691.pdf) the modulation seems to be FSK (which Wikipedia says is Frequency-shift keying). But that's not available on the Flipper Zero, it just has HND, Pagers, FM{15k, 95, 476, 238,}, AM{650, 270},

- It seems Flipper Unleashed "custom presets" for FM95, FM15K, Pagers, and HND. [defined in subghz.c](https://github.com/DarkFlippers/unleashed-firmware/blob/92bed4a081bdb0843d0c130428ad1e02ab528044/applications/main/subghz/subghz.c#L57). None of these presets worked.
- The expanded names of the other modulations can also be found in [`subghz.c`](https://github.com/DarkFlippers/unleashed-firmware/blob/dev/lib/subghz/blocks/generic.c#L7). This makes me think the "FM" means FSK. But having tested it none of the FM modulations worked.

I found the rtl 433 project, [which claims it can decode Honda Keys](https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/blob/f9dc6b882e2b4f98a7334887d41f85579152c512/src/devices/hondaremote.c#L33), it seems it's using a preset called `FSK_PULSE_PWM`.

Comment: May be worth giving [URH](https://github.com/jopohl/urh) a shot if it's able to find anything interesting.